# How to open search results in a new tab on Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, browser-tabs

When I make a search from the upper right search box of Firefox, the results are always opened on the current tab. It's annoying because it loads the results over the tab I'm monitoring, and then I have to move back to find my page again after I'm finished with the search affair. I want Firefox to open the results always in a new tab. Is it possible?

Comment: Not an answer, but a workaround: press Ctrl-T/Command-T first, to get a new tab *before* searching? (Then hit Ctrl-L/Command-L to jump into the location field, and Tab to get to the search field.)

Comment: Arjan: Or just hit Alt+Enter for searching. Works with the address bar, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to `about:config` in the address bar, filter to `browser.search.openintab` and set it to **true**. This will open search results from the search box in a new tab.

[image]

You can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when searching to open it in a new tab.

Comment: That's it! I'm relieved now...